# How to add "Create database" command in mysql backup file

Tags: mysql, bash, cygwin

I need to create database dump. I use this command in Cygwin. OS is Windows 7.

```
mysqldump -u "root" -P "3306" -h "127.0.0.1" "my_db" > "$dump_path"
```

My file "$dump_path" not contains "Create database" command line. How to add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you prefix the database name by `-B`  , mysqldump will add `CREATE DATABASE` statement

```
mysqldump -u "root" -P "3306" -h "127.0.0.1" -B "my_db" > "$dump_path"
```

references :

```
 --no-create-db
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-db

```
 --databases
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases